# Jaxb2 maven plugin : Sources vs SchemaDirectory

Tags: maven, jaxb2-maven-plugin

I am making a maven project that will make use of Jaxb2-maven-plugin to generate java files out of xsd files. My Project structure is like:

```
project.basedir
--src/main/resources/schemas
----common
----request
----response
```

Below is the plugin config from pom.xml

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.6</version>

    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>xjc-PDF</id>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>xjc</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <extension>true</extension>
                <clearOutputDir>false</clearOutputDir>
                <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/jaxb</outputDirectory>
                <explicitAnnotation>true</explicitAnnotation>
                <!-- <schemaDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/schemas</schemaDirectory> -->
                <sources>
                    <source>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/schemas/common</source>
                    <source>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/schemas/response</source>
                    <source>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/schemas/request</source>
                </sources>
                <bindingDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/schemas</bindingDirectory>
                <!-- <bindingDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/bindings</bindingDirectory> -->
                <bindingFiles>jaxb-bth.xjb</bindingFiles>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

If I compile like this then I get below error (even though the source directories contains valid schema files):

```
C:\ESB_SOAP5_Space\pdf-util>mvn clean install
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building pdf-util 1.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ pdf-util ---
[INFO] Deleting C:\ESB_SOAP5_Space\pdf-util\target
[INFO]
[INFO] --- build-helper-maven-plugin:1.6:add-source (add-source) @ pdf-util ---
[INFO] Source directory: C:\ESB_SOAP5_Space\pdf-util\target\generated-sources\jaxb added.
[INFO]
[INFO] --- jaxb2-maven-plugin:1.6:xjc (xjc-PDF) @ pdf-util ---
[INFO] Generating source...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2.205 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-03-19T06:27:02+11:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 8M/245M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:jaxb2-maven-plugin:1.6:xjc (xjc-PDF) on project pdf-util: No schemas have been found -> [Help 1]
```

However, if I comment sources and uncomment and modify  like below, then I am able to generate java classes out of schemas under common.

```
<schemaDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/schemas/common</schemaDirectory>
```

Can anyone tell me why is this behaving like this? Also what do I do if I have to parse all the schema files under one root folder ( which has multiple child folders)?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Version 1.6 of the plugin does not support "sources" tag. You can use "sources tag on version 2.4 or newer.

If you have multiple directories containing xsds, use multiple executions in your configuration with each schemaDirectory pointing to one of your directories.